# How to read json from remote in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

I have tried to read a json from remote server, then i got this error.

> "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows
>   reading the remote resource"

Then i read that i need to set the datatype to `jsonp`.

```
  dataType: 'jsonp',
```

The problem is the json that i am getting isn't in `jsonp` format, which is required by `jsonp`. If i don't use jsonp i get the above error message.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: if the server offers no jsonp, and no cors headers, you need a server side (your server) solution

Comment: @JaromandaX : I am trying not to add more load in my server.

Comment: in that case, the only option is to contact the owner of the remote site and get them to support either `jsonp` or add CORS headers for you

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable a CORS request on the server side as well.

Add this line to your code:
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

You can replace * with your site's url if you want to allow only for particular domain.